# WebSocket no se conecta a mi servidor localhost:8080 u otros puertos hechos en PYTHON

Tags: javascript, python

necesito ayuda. me disculpo si estoy cometiendo alguna ignorancia. pero de los errores se aprende....

lo que quiero hacer es un chat en tiempo real con webSockets. luego de descubrir que el localhost de xampp no es un servidor para websockets investigue como levantar un servidor local. use python para hacer el servidor local asignandole el puerto 8080

**C:\Users\Leonel\Desktop\chatWS>python -m http.server 8080**

luego me sale lo siguiente

**Serving HTTP on :: port 8080 (http://[::]:8080/) ...**

en el directorio **chatWS** tengo mis archivos **index.html** y **script.js**
dentro del script.js tengo el siguiente codigo

**const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");**

```
ws.onopen = function(e) {
console.log('conectado');
```

}

al momento de abrir un navegador y poner mi localhost:8080 en inspeccion de elemento **consola** me aparece lo siguiente

**Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://localhost:8080/.**

si reconoce mi archivo .html pero el ws no se conecta...el problema no solo es en el firefox. sino en todos los navegadores que tengo. ya intente asignandole otro puerto... me atrevo a decir que ya intente todo lo que tengo a mi alcance... si alguien me puede ayudar en que estoy haciendo mal...

PD: no tengo ejecutado el xampp y tambien lo probe ejecutandolo y el problema sigue ahi

adjunto algunas capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ARCHIVO .js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes una mezcla de conceptos bastante fuerte. Te sugiero seguir la [documentación](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html). El protocolo `ws` y el protocolo `http` son muy diferentes. Tu tienes en Python un servidor `http`, lo que te hace falta es un servidor `ws`. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias... la verdad no me habia dado cuenta de mi error... gracias de verdad